# Prevent browser from snapping to previous scroll position on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my `AJAX` application, there is a main page with folders that contain images. When the user clicks a folder it hides the folders and then repopulates the same div with images from that folder. This is all done using hashtags.

Everything works great until they click the back button.

When the user clicks the back button, this happens (in sequence, every time):

1. the very first thing that happens is the browser snaps down to where it just was when last visiting that hash
2. my `hashchange` event is called which removes the thumbnails
3. now that there is not enough of a content height after the thumbnails have been removed, the window has to snap back up to a scrollTop of 0 as there is, for a split second, no scrollbar
4. *then* the folders are shown again
5. *then* my script kicks in to restore the user to where they were on the page

The problem: This creates really bad `flickering` because of how much the scrollbar is being snapped around.

The solution: Making the browser not try to restore its scroll position when the hash changes.

How do I know this will work? When I set up a button/link on my site to do the above, the flickering does not occur because the browser does not automatically try to scroll down. Why can't putting my own back button on the site be the solution? People really like their browser back button and the flickering is *really* annoying.

I included some code below, but I don't think it is really necessary to look at:

```
// called when a folder is clicked
function hide_main() {
    window.scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('#favorite_container').hide();
    $('#top_div > h2.favorite_main').hide();
}

// called when the user wants to go back to the main page that lists all the folders
function show_main() {
    $$.vars.lock = true;

    $('#top_div > h2.favorite_other').remove();
    $('#thumbs').empty();

    $('#top_div > h2.favorite_main').show();
    $('#favorite_container').show();

    $('html, body').scrollTop(window.scroll_top);
}
```

So how do I go about stopping the browser from doing its default behaviour of scrolling to the position it previously was when the back button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it so the body does not scroll; only elements inside the body scroll. e.g.

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>

#content {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Thus the browser will always think the body is at 0% scroll.

Comment: That will cause the `#content` div to have scrollbars on it though, right? That will look a lot worse than the flicker, but thanks for trying (:

Comment: @Conner: I don't think that is true. It will not have scrollbars if your page doesn't need scrollbars (e.g. you can set `overflow:hidden` if you need to). It will have scrollbars exactly where you'd have scrollbars if you didn't use this method. It's practically indistinguishable from a not using this technique. Except it probably fools the browser into not scrolling on a back button.

Comment: Thanks for the response but make sure to do @Connor instead so I get a notification :) I'll try it, but I'm pretty sure this will create another scrollbar just for the div itself in addition to the standard document scrollbar

Comment: @Connor: the idea here is to remove the standard document scrollbar and replace it with an artificial one, keeping everything else the same

Comment: Having another scrollbar on the page really won't fly design-wise :(

Comment: @Connor: As I've said (for the third time =) you are not adding a scrollbar to the page.

Comment: You originally had it as `overflow:scroll-x` (which it should actually be `overflow-x:scroll`) which would add a scrollbar. The problem now with `overflow:hidden` is it restricts the div height to the document height, is there a way around this?

Comment: @Connor: There is nothing to work around. What is the issue, and why do you feel the height is "restricted"? Your content is either small enough to fit in there, or too big to fit in there. If it's too big, how do you intend for the user or javascript to move the content around?

Comment: Let's say there is *2000px* of content height-wise inside of `#content` but the browser window is only *1000px* high. *1000px* of content will be `cut off` since you have overflow set to **hidden**. If you set overflow-y to scroll then there will be a scrollbar.

Comment: @Connor: As I asked, how do you intend for the user to view those extra pixels? If not via scrolling? Either you want a scrollbar or you don't want a scrollbar. I am very confused, which is it?

Comment: It has to be via scrolling... if there was no scrolling there would be no problem.

Comment: No, no I want a scrollbar. But just the browser scrollbar, not another one for the div specifically which you will get if you set overflow-y:scroll 100% of the time.

Comment: Okay let me be more specific, this div is at 100% width, it isn't just like 15% of the page so that is why another scrollbar is out of the question

Comment: @Connor: OKAY. There we go. The **real** problem is, is that you won't want to see the scrollbar 100% of the time. (Otherwise the scrollbars are exactly the same and you can't tell the difference.) This "scrollbar 100% of the time" issue should not be the case, and indicates a CSS issue with the browser. Make sure that `body {margin:0px; padding:0px;}`

Comment: I really don't think you understand. I'll make a jsfiddle, just a sec

Comment: @Connor: "Okay let me be more specific, this div is at 100% width, it isn't just like 15% of the page so that is why another scrollbar is out of the question" what do you mean? why? You have said you want something exactly like a scrollbar on `body`, yet why is this an issue?

Comment: `You have said you want something exactly like a scrollbar on body` Because no matter what, no matter what website you go to, there is a scrollbar on your browser. Sometimes it is all grayed out and sometimes it is not, this is expected behavior. Unexpected behavior would be to have a rogue scrollbar. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/XmacF/

Comment: @Connor: I understood perfectly. Your solution is here http://jsfiddle.net/72cBn/ using exactly my original code. It does exactly what you want. Good night.

Comment: I had set a height for html which seemed to mess things up. Thank you for helping. Good night.